# JQuery Mobile 1.4 custom icon in header not showing

Tags: jquery-mobile, header, icons

I'm having a problem with custom icons in header. Followed the instruction on demo page and worked on panel; however, still not get any clue why those in header wouldn't show up.

Here is my code http://jsfiddle.net/kukubag/z257dngf/3/

```
<div data-role="page" id="fpost-page" data-url="fpost-page" data-theme="f">
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="f">
    <a href="#left-panel" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-left ui-iconmenu"></a>
    <span class="ui-title"></span>
    <a href="#note-editor-page" class="ui-btn-icon-notext ui-iconnew"></a>
</div>
```

```
.ui-iconmenu:after {
background-image: url("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/67263773/travelogue/img/icmenu.png");
background-size: 22px 22px;
```

}

```
.ui-iconnew:after {
background-image: url("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/67263773/travelogue/img/icnew.png");
background-size: 22px 22px;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a dash inyour custom icon names: ui-icon-menu and ui-icon-new:

```
.ui-icon-menu:after {
    background-image: url("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/67263773/travelogue/img/icmenu.png");
    background-size: 22px 22px;
    border-radius:0;
}
.ui-icon-new:after {
    background-image: url("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/67263773/travelogue/img/icnew.png");
    background-size: 22px 22px;
    border-radius:0;
}
```

> Here is your updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/z257dngf/5/)**

Comment: Thanks! It seems to work in Fiddle only. The icons are still invisible  after I edited and open the page in Chrome. Would the version of CDN be the problem of that? I use them all in latest version now.

Comment: in your fiddle you only loaded the structure css. Do you have your own theme css? As long as you are using 1.4.x of jQM this CSS should work.

Comment: I relinked the sources again and it worked! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Your first URL is wrong: you wrote `url("https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/appicns/513/appicns_Chrome.png.png");` with 2 times `.png`

Replace with `url("https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/appicns/513/appicns_Chrome.png");`

And why did you use `:after` in your css?

Check here: http://jsfiddle.net/nrobert/z257dngf/4/
I also added the script in the right way in the fiddle (need to be added on the left pane)